# Is checking for the existence of a key in a dictionary better than catching a KeyError in Python?

Tags: python, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I have a bit of experience in Python but I'm taking the Udacity computer science course to fill in the gaps of what I've learned and to supplement what I already know. The course went over a hashtable lookup function that returns None for the value of a key if the key isn't in the hashtable. Python's dictionary type throws a KeyError when the key doesn't exist, so the course says to use `key in mydict` before getting its value.

What I'm wondering is if it's better to do:

```
mydefaultval = 75
key = ..
mydict = ..
if key in mydict:
    val = mydict[key]
else:
    val = mydefaultval
```

.. or

```
mydefaultval = 75
key = ..
mydict = ..
try:
    val = mydict[key]
except KeyError:
    val = mydefaultval
```

I would imagine that for Python to check if the key exists, it has to find it in the dictionary. If I then grab the value at that key, it has to do the same thing twice. Am I correct for thinking this, or will Python do something else?

Comment: Ned has given you the right answer - but it's worth advising that you shouldn't shadow built-ins (such as naming a dict - dict).

In general Python follows the "Better to ask forgiveness than permission", rather than the "Look before you leap" approach. 

ie, don't see if you can do it first, just try to do it, and if you can't, then handle it.

Comment: @JonClements, Sorry, forgot about that. I just wanted to type the example up quickly.

Comment: While in your situation there are other answers, Jon Clements is right - you are almost always better off catching the exception - for one, it generally shows the right priority - you want to deal with what happens when everything is as you expect first, not think about checks. It also avoids race conditions in a wide range of situations, which is always worth doing, as they are subtle and annoying bugs to catch if they slip in.

Comment: @Lattyware, That's another thing I didn't think of. You're saying that there's the possibility of the key being deleted after checking for its presence but before getting its values, right?

Comment: Yup - it's not normally a problem for something like a dict key, but where threads are involved, or writing/reading to/from files, it's a serious concern. In general, it's best to stick to handling exceptions rather than checking before unless you absolutely need to (for example, if that section of code is a vital bottleneck and the exceptional case actually happens quite a lot - although note if the exceptional case happens most of the time, you might be able to swap around what the exceptional case is as an alternative - but obviously, never optimise unless you have to.).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best thing is to use dict.get:

```
val = my_dict.get(key, mydefaultval)
```

If there weren't an awesome method like this, I'd recommend using the exception.  Python culture is that exceptions are not forbidden, and often the explicit check will actually be catching exceptions anyway.

Comment: Would you say that this applies to other languages that support functions for checking for a key but not for getting a default value?

Comment: If it were performance critical and there weren't an awesome method like this, I would use the exception only if I expected that the value was usually present.  But it's probably best to code whatever is clearest first and worry about performance if you find a bottleneck.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, Do you mean that the other way around? Only use the exception if you expect the value to usually not be present?

Comment: Also, Ned, thank you for answering the question even though the built-in function exists.

Comment: Worth noting that the dict.get() implementation is AFAIK not laid in stone. An implementation is welcome to effectively construct it as a try/except block. I haven't had to delve into the source of Python implementations for a long time though, so they might be doing something a bit smarter behind the hood.

Answer (score 0):

If the default is going to be the same value every time you use a particular dict, another option is to use `collections.defaultdict`. It's more verbose to declare the dict than the `dict.get()` solution, but much terser in usage:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> mydict = defaultdict( lambda: 75 )
>>> mydict[3]
75
```